# Parse (parse-server): Code 111 Schema mismatch when trying to add Relation using REST API

Tags: rest, curl, parse-platform, parse-server

I am running parse-server 2.2.13. While trying to add a relation through the REST API:

```
curl -X PUT -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APP_ID" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: API_KEY" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"user":{"__op":"AddRelation","objects":[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"User","objectId":"xgp8q3s5Bq"}]}}' http://my.parse.server/parse/classes/Question/5F6ZSGpvLX
```

I am getting this error: `{"code":111,"error":"schema mismatch for Question.user; expected Relation but got [object Object]"}`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, or if I am missing something completely. On the dashboard, I have created a user column on the Question class with Pointer type having User as the target class. I tried using both Pointer type as well as Relation type, and still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I just found an answer myself, partly based on this: [Can't get pointer to work with REST API "can't add a relation to an non-relation field"](https://www.parse.com/questions/cant-get-pointer-to-work-with-rest-api-cant-add-a-relation-to-an-non-relation-field)

This is what I had to do to make it work:

```
curl -X PUT -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APP_ID" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: API_KEY" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"user":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"xgp8q3s5Bq"}}' http://my.parse.server/parse/classes/Question/5F6ZSGpvLX
```

There are two things that should be noted:

1. Contrary to what the documentation says, __op AddRelation is not used
2. I should be using _User as the class name instead of User

Apparently, two years has past since that post (the link above), and the documentation was still never updated :(